# duplicating an array of strings (or copying them to another array)?

Tags: c, string, pointers, arguments

I need the arguments that were passed to my process when it was started.
This means, of `argv[]` I need all but the first (which is my process's name).

I am having trouble copying it, because of it being type `char * argv[]`. 
Can anyone give me the gist of how to do it properly, or perhaps a small code snippet. I'd prefer that to banging my head on the wall.

### EDIT:

Clarifying my problem:

The key thing is I need all but the first argument of argv. So i can't just send it off to other processes, as I am actually using it as an argument to execv.

Comment: Then just pass argv + 1 to execv.  That is the array of arguments minus the first.

Comment: execv takes the same argument list, including argv[0]. The only reason you would need to copy it is if you need to change argv[0].

Comment: @fizzer That's wrong -- execv needs the 0th argument.

Comment: Hmmm - on reflection, he can't assume argv ends with a null pointer, as required by execv

Comment: Yes - he needs to make a copy.

Comment: @fizzer execv implies a POSIX system, and the POSIX standard says "The last member of this array shall be a NULL pointer" -- so that **can** be assumed.

Comment: @Jim, I don't understand how this is possible. My first program would have the argument list 'pname otherpname -arg1 -arg2 -arg3', and I want to use execv to call otherpname with -arg1 -arg2 -arg3.

Comment: @fizzer In fact, even the C Standard says "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer".

Comment: @Jim good point again.  I dimly thought it might be, but worried that I was confusing it with environ.

Comment: @Blackbinary Read the execv man page.If you call otherpname with -arg1 -arg2 -arg3, -arg1 will be interpreted by otherpname as the program name if otherpname follows convention. Of course if you write it, it can do what you want, but if you don't follow that convention then it won't work properly with the shell or other POSIX tools.

Comment: @Blackbinary And, as I said, "The only reason you would need to copy it is if you need to change argv[0]" .. e.g., if you needed to change argv[0] from "pname" to "otherpname". It's probably a good idea to do that, but it isn't strictly necessary unless the otherpname program uses its argv[0] to decide how to behave.

Comment: @Blackbinary "My first program would have the argument list 'pname otherpname -arg1 -arg2 -arg3'" ... if that's truly the case, then you **can** do as fizzer said: simply pass argv+1 to execv. It's a good idea to include **all** the details of your problem in your questions so as to maximize the help you receive.

Comment: Well then, its actually a command like: `scavenger USER=2.00 BUSY= 50.00 IDLE=30.00 ls -l` So i would have to shave off 4 commands. but if the principle is the same, i could just pass argv+4?

Comment: @Blackbinary Yes, argv+4 would point to [ls -l] which is exactly the argument list that you want to pass to ls.

Comment: @fizzer Ironically, your very first comment appears to be the right answer! You might want to update your answer below to reflect the comments here, and hopefully the OP will accept yours.

Comment: hmm.. i've made this small program to illustrate your example. but it doesnt seem to output anything to the term. http://pastebin.com/PKXPksNe it gets pname correctly... just the actual execv doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Blackbinary See the edit to my answer. execv is failing because it can't find "ls", and you're not checking its return value, which you always do,  even (or especially) in test snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote in a comment "My first program would have the argument list 'pname otherpname -arg1 -arg2 -arg3', and I want to use execv to call otherpname with -arg1 -arg2 -arg3." In that case, the argument list you want to pass to execv is [otherpname -arg1 -arg2 -arg3] ... the argument list passed to execv is exactly what otherpname's main routine will see as argv, and it must include argv[0] which is conventionally the program name. Conveniently, that list is exactly what argv + 1 points to ... no need to copy anything.

[edit]
However, you do have the problem of what to pass to execv as *its* first argument -- the file name of the program to exec. Either otherpname needs to be a fully qualified path or you should use execvp, which searches PATH for the program.

Comment: I appreciate all the help (seriously,you've been helping for almost an hour). You right, the trick was using execvp. I think my biggest hurdle was realizing that regardless of which part of argv i point to, it contains the rest of the list. So argv+5 contains all arguments after 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's no point copying the strings - they will persist for the lifetime of the program and you aren't allowed to modify them. Just pass argc and argv around to whoever needs them, or copy them to global variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myargc;
char **myargv;

void print_args()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < myargc; ++i) {
        puts(myargv[i]);
    }
}    


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    myargc = argc;
    myargv = argv;

    print_args();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `argv` is a `char **`, if necessary you could just store the argv pointer to a global variable of this type.

Otherwise, to copy it you need to allocate an array and copy the pointers. If you don't need to copy the strings themselves too, something like this should work:

```
char **copy_of_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (argc-1));
memcpy(copy_of_argv, argv + 1, sizeof(char *) * (argc - 1));
```

(although you may or may not want to allocate an extra slot in `copy_of_argv` for a terminiating NULL pointer as a sentinel).

If you need to copy the strings too for some unknown reason, it's a little more complicated:

```
int i;
char **copy_of_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (argc-1));
for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
    copy_of_argv[i] = strdup(argv[i + 1]);
}
```

(again, you may want to allocate an extra slot for a sentinel).

Comment: I did this: http://pastebin.com/UAeRuS10 
But i get a segfault on the memcopy :(. Any ideas why?

Comment: For one, you are probably accessing beyond the end of `argv` unless `nArgs` is less than `argc-5`. For another, you forgot the parentheses in the malloc, so you wound up allocating space for nArgs `char *`s plus 1 byte rather than space for (nAgrs+1) `char *`s. And for a third, to set `args[nArgs+1]` you would have to malloc at least `sizeof(char *)*(nArgs+2)` bytes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a modifyable copy of the arguments do this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main(int argc, char** argv) {
            int myargc = argc;
            char** myargv = malloc( (argc-1)*sizeof(void*));
            int i;
            for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
                    int len = strlen(argv[i]);
                    myargv[i-1] = malloc(len+1);
                    memcpy(myargv[i-1], argv[i], len+1); // +1 so \0 copied too.
            }               
            getch();
    }
```

Comment: need to add a 0 to the end of all copied char*

Comment: @JaDogg thanks, I changed the memcpy-line. very useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that you should say :

> The key thing is I need all but the first argument of argv. So i can't
>   just send it off to other processes, as I am actually using it as an
>   argument to execv

This sounds a lot like what I am doing where I want to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then run a binary using my own copy of ld.so so that no default system shared libraries are used at all. The arg to execve is my copy of ld.so but once the real binary starts I want its argv to look normal (and environ). Here's how I did it on Linux:

```
include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PYBINARY "/data1/packages/python272/bin/python"
#define LDSO "/data1/packages/python272/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
#define MYLIBS "/data1/packages/python272/lib"

extern char **environ;

main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
  int retcode;
  char **e;
  char **myargv;

  setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH",MYLIBS,1);
  setenv("_",PYBINARY,1);

  /* copy argv */
  int i = 0;
  myargv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 100);
  for(;argv[i] != NULL; i++) {
    myargv[i+1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(argv[i]) + 1));
    memcpy(myargv[i+1], argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
  }
  myargv[i+1] = NULL;
  myargv[0] = LDSO;
  myargv[1] = PYBINARY;

  e = myargv;
  while (*e != NULL){
    printf("arg: %s\n",*e++);
  }

  retcode = execve(LDSO, myargv, environ);
  perror("exec2: execve() failed");
  exit(1);
}
```

If you put this in test.py:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
import os
print os.environ["_"]
```

and run it with `python -i test.py` you will get the same results as `./mypy -i test.py` so anything dependent on the argv or envp will not break.

Comment: sizeof(char) is always 1, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access one of the argv strings do this:

printf("%s", argv[0]);

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you need to do with the arguments?

arg[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/), arg[2], arg[3]... etc are simple C strings (char*).

If you *need* to copy them to another array, you can use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) function (e.g. `strcpy(destination,arg[1])`, but since the values of the parameters are not going to change, you most likely do not have to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

For execv, something like this, then

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char** myargs;

    if (argc <= 0)
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    myargs = malloc(sizeof *myargs * (argc + 1));

    myargs[0] = "your_program_name_here"; 
    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        myargs[i] = argv[i];
    }
    myargs[argc] = 0;
    execv("/your/program/here", myargs);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```